# An exception occur during assign a value in a for loop : DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array

Tags: matlab

I've tried to find the answer to this simple for loop question but I can't find any tutorials on it. 
I ran gen_R(16, 0.0832) and there would be an exception occur when m=1,p=16.
However, I ran gen_R(16, 0.5) and everything is ok.
I'm really curies about the reason.

My script reads as follows:

```
function [U,D]= gen_R(num_antenna,theta)

AS=pi/180*8;
frequency=20*10^9;
lamda=3*10^8/frequency;
R=zeros(num_antenna);
syms x;
for m=1:1:num_antenna
    for p=1:1:num_antenna
        d=abs(m-p);

        R(m,p)=(1/(2*AS))*int(exp(-1i*2*pi*d*sin(x+theta)/lamda),-1*AS,AS);
    end
end
[U,D]=eig(R);

end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: The exception is "DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array". And matlab said this error occur at "R(m, p) = ...."